# Change text color in text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input text field, which has a value "something" by default, but when I start to type, I want that the default value changes color, and the text i'll type, another one.

How can i do that?

---

```
<input type="text" value="something" onclick="this.value=''" />
```

Comment: I assume you mean an input text box?  A button cannot have text typed into it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To keep it simple like your example:

```
<input type="text" value="something" onclick="this.value='';this.style.color='red';" />
```

And that should pretty much do it.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to try the following:

```
<input type="text" value="something"
       onFocus="if (this.value == 'something') this.style.color = '#ccc';"
       onKeyDown="if (this.value == 'something') {  
                      this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000'; }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off @chibu's answer, this is how you would do it using jQuery and unobtrusive Javascript

```
 
$(document).ready(
   function() {
      $("#mytext").bind(
         "click",
         function() {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).css("color", "red");
         }
      );
   }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// 'run' is an id for button and 'color' is for input tag

// code starts here
(function () {
    
    const button = document.getElementById("run");
    button.addEventListener("click", colorChange);

    function colorChange() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("color").value;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the thread owner didn't mention a button in their requirements.

Answer (score -3):

Here we go:

```
<input type="text" value="something" onclick="this.value='';this.style.color='red';" />
```

Best of luck!

Keep coding!