# How to Change font color by input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have to change font color by get user input in Javascript. here is the HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="keywords" content="JavaScript, UserInput" />
        <title>JavaScript accept user input demo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function displayOutput() {
                var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
                if (input.length === 0) {
                    alert("Please enter a valid input");
                    return;
                }
               document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = input;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="result">Example</h1>
        <input type="text" id="userInput"  />
        <select name="color" type="text" >
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="displayOutput()" />
</body>    
</html>
```

Could please help me to change the result font color.?

Comment: document.getElementById("result").style.color ???

Comment: What did you find when you googled your question and what didn't work?

Comment: Nope its not working..:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text color in text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516784/change-text-color-in-text-field)

Comment: This may help: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/9447kneh/

Comment: @PhilCooper, No buddy!

Comment: result(font color) should change when i select it from drop drown.

Comment: Thanks Rayon. This is what i expect.:). like that can change the font size too ?

Comment: @RayonDabre opps, that would be the case doing it programmatically #failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use style.color. Use the following code.

```
document.getElementById("userInput").style.color=document.getElementById('color').value
```

Refer the jsfiddle sample.

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/22891/

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font color by updating the style attribute of the element with the id of result in the displayOutput function:

```
function displayOutput() {
var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
var color = document.querySelector('select[name="color"]').value;
if (input.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid input");
    return;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = input;
document.getElementById("result").style.color = color;
```

}